# ./bin/hadoop command does not return any usage documentation

Tags: hadoop, terminal

I am getting started with hadoop. I installed java. Set Java_Home to 1.8 and installed hadoop.2.7.6 and I cd'ed into the hadoop installation directory to run bin/hadoop. How ever I donot see any output. I have also tried one of the examples using the command

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.6.jar
```

Initially

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some issue with version 2.7.6. I installed version 2.7.7 and it started to work.